# Recursion for counting valid strings (Generatingfunctionology chapter 1, problem 20)

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, recursion

> Let $f(n, m, k)$ be the number of strings of $n$ $0$’s and $1$’s that contain exactly $m$ $1$’s, no $k$ of which are consecutive.
>
> (a) Find a recurrence formula for $f$. It should have $f(n, m, k)$ on the left side, and exactly three terms on the right.

My attempted answer is as follows (I am not sure if this is correct):

$$f(n,m,k) = f(n-1,m,k) + f(n-1,m-1,k) - f(n-k,m-k,k)$$

The reasoning is: counting the number of strings with $0$ as the last entry, plus the number of strings with $1$ as the last entry, minus the number of strings ending in $k$ $1$'s.

I am not sure how to start (b) or (c):
(b) Find in simplest form the generating functions
$$F_k(x,y) = \sum_{n,m \geq 0}f(n,m,k)x^ny^m$$

(c) Find an explicit formula for $f(n,m,k)$ from the generating function (this should involve only a single summation,
of an expression that involves a few factorials).

Comment: I derived the exact same answer, by the same reasoning as you described.

Comment: @user2661923 I am unsure of how to do part b of this question, due to the initial conditions varying depending on k.

Comment: For (b), you start by replacing $f(n,m,k)$ by the right-hand side of the formula you proved in (a); then, manipulating each of the three resulting sums into looking like $F_r(s,t)$ for some values of $r,s,t$ in terms of $n,m,k$ but multiplied by appropriate powers of $x$ and/or $y$; then seeing what cancellations you get.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am having some trouble doing this because I am unsure what to do about the initial values. Here is an example: if we have a simple recursion $f(n+1) = 2f(n)$ then rewriting as a generating function we would get $\frac{F(x) - f(0)}{x} = 2F(x)$ in this case I need to subtract out the $x^0$ term since $f(n+1)$ starts at $1$.  I am not sure about how to account for this in this more complicated case.

Comment: I think it will come to you if you do as I have suggested. Please, try it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think I am doing this wrong, I always get that the generating function divides out. I write $$F_k(x,y) = xyF_k(x,y) + xF_k - x^ky^kF_k(x,y)$$

Comment: I suspect that when you do that you're not paying attention to the lowest order terms.